# What are the differences between Cryptonight-R and Cryptonight v4?

Tags: cryptonight, proof-of-work

Monero is switching to Cryptonight variant 4 (CNv4) in March 2019. CNv4 is based on Cryptonight-R, with some modifications. What are these modifications ?

Answer (score 1):

> What are the differences between Cryptonight-R and Cryptonight v4?

They are the one and the same thing [[src]](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/commit/1b77e80a7851a0a69da1111db0b4be8f3e668884), just different naming.

```
Cryptonight variant 4 aka CryptonightR
```

More accurately though, CryptonightR is proof-of-concept code and Cryptonight-v4 is Monero's implementation of it [[src]](https://github.com/SChernykh/CryptonightR#cryptonightr).

```
This is proof of concept repository and a proposal for the next Monero PoW. 
It introduces random integer math into CryptonightV2 main loop.
```

> ...with some modifications. What are these modifications ?

Just some final tweaks from vtnerd [[src]](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/commit/c2b8037a4296a542fd4170c86b0914b5f6470f5b). These are not fundamental changes, rather last minute "tweaks".

These last minute tweaks ensure the original developer of the implementation hasn't also secretly developed an ASIC capable of working with the implementation, and also any other ASIC manufacturers that might have been developing an ASIC whilst the code was available before being PRed to Monero.

Of the tweaks themselves, the addition of an extra register and more memory access routines seem to be the significant tweaks.

Comment: "aka": Also Known As - this is in the commit message by the author.

Comment: The only changes I'm aware of to was merged into Wownero are vtnerd's tweaks (and maybe a couple of other minor bug fixes/tweaks). For all intents and purposes, they are the same, save vtnerd's tweaks.

Comment: Are you saying vtnerd's tweaks are in wownero too ? If that's the case, then they'd be the same indeed, but my understanding was that they had not been. Can you confirm ? Your wording is not clear :)

Comment: No, I don't believe vtnerd's patch is in Wownero. Can see how my comment was misleading! Typo/ autocorrect. The only change to CN-R, that's in Monero I meant.

Comment: Reviewing vtnerd's patch, the significant part of the tweak looks to be the addition of an extra register.

Comment: Where's the extra memory dependency? Do you mean because of the extra reg or the CN scratchpad (which remains the same size) or something else?

Comment: See the patch, in the VARIANT2_SHUFFLE_ADD_SSE2 macro for example.

Comment: Please explain how that's an "extra memory dependency".

Comment: https://github.com/SChernykh/CryptonightR#the-second-tweak-from-vtnerd

Comment: I can only assume you mean extra memory access access dependencies. But please clarify.

Comment: Yes, I mean memory.